# Storing Application Settings in a Visual Studio Cordova Project

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

Cordova 5.1.1 with Ionic on Visual Studio 2015.

I am looking to store key-value (string, string) read-only application settings and the ability to change the settings in different compilation modes (i.e. debug and release mode), in a similar fashion to web.config, web.debug.config and web.release.config of ASP.NET. Obviously, these settings should be read easily from the JS files and having them unsecure is not an issue.

An example configuration is the AuthenticationApiUri that will vary between development and release.

Is there any standard way to do that?

Comment: This question came up for our project as well. We looked around for a while and what we ended up doing is creating a config.js file and have all settings as properties of a config object.

Comment: @EladLachmi, it looks like there is no standard way.